# Is it true that in $Mat(n,n) $ the set of singular matrices forms a hyperplane?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Is it true that in $Mat(n,n)$ the set of singular matrices forms a hyperplane, separating the matrices of positive determinant from the matrices of negative determinant?

This is my intuition, but it's not obvious to me how to prove it. Clearly all matrices of the same determinant sign are connected by a line...

Comment: No. $\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$ $+\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix} $

Comment: Yet, when $n>1$, for every singular matrix $A$, we can always find a nontrivial matrix subspace consisting of singluar matrices, including $A$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not true. A hyperplane would have to be given by a linear equation. Think about the space of two-by-two matrices:

$$\det\left[\begin{array}{cc} a & b \\ c & d \end{array}\right] = ad-bc$$

The singular matrices have $ad-bc=0$. This is a homogeneous equation of degree two, and will give a three-dimensional cone in the four-dimensional $abcd$-space.

In general, the determinant of an $n$-by-$n$ matrix will be a [homogeneous polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_polynomial) of degree $n$.

Comment: Thanks. In general is the set of singular matrices a hypercone, then?

Comment: That's right, yes. Notice that cone doesn't have to be an ordinary circular cone. For example there are elliptical, parabolic and hyperbolic cones. In general, you have a cone "over" some base. In the two-by-two case, the base of the cone $ad-bc$ will be given by a two dimensional surface in three space. (In general you'll have a cone over a hypersurface.)